# I copied a code from font awesome to make my Navbar mobile responsive, but it's not working. I'm using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I aimed to create a mobile-responsive Navbar, and in pursuit of this goal, I copied the script tag provided by Font Awesome. Following that, I included "fas fa-bars" in my code. However, the desired result was not achieved; instead, it only displayed the checkbox.

```html
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js" crossorigin=" anonymous"></script>" 

 

    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
```

I attempted to download a web font, but when I utilized the link provided by the web font, an unexpected outcome occurred. Specifically, everything within the navbar would suddenly vanish, leaving only the anticipated burger icon visible after the text had disappeared.

here's the link I used

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"  integrity="sha512z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA=="crossorigin="anonymous"referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
```

Comment: Is the tab actually present (between `font-` and `awesome`) in the link href? If so I would try removing that, as it will definitely break the link.